# Python RPi - File not found when running script from another script

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to run a python script from another python script on a Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian. I've been trying to find ways to do this for some hours and didn't find anything that worked. I've tried some ways but it either says that has not permission to execute the file or it can't find it. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I need to run multiple instances of the other script through the main script in a new console (new processes) and keep them running (I don't expect them to return anything to the main script). Can anyone help me? Because with Windows it was really easy as the program was working fine until I tried to run it on Linux (with Windows, I used os.startfile).

**In test.py:**

```
print("test1")
input()
```

**In main.py:**

```
import os
import subprocess
print("main")
os.system("python test.py")
input()
```

In the console:
main
python: can't open file 'test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

**In main.py:**

```
import os
import subprocess
print("main")
subprocess.Popen("python test.py",shell=True)
input()
```

In the console:
main
python: can't open file 'test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

**In main.py:**

```
import os
import subprocess
print("main")
subprocess.call("python test.py",shell=True)
input()
```

In the console:
main
python: can't open file 'test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I tried more ways but I don't remember them. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

EDIT: I can now run the scripts without any problems with os.chdir (thanks to J H). My problem now is that it prints test in the same console window as the main.py and I needed it to create another process for the test.py. Any solutions?

EDIT 2: Finally I could start a new processes of the test.py from the main.py! I used os.system('xdg-open "test.py"') to open test.py with the default application. Anyway thanks to J H, otherwise it would continue to say file not found.

**Final main.py:**

```
import os
print("main")
os.chdir('/home/pi/Desktop/')
os.system('xdg-open test.py')
input()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are these files in the same dir? Your code works for me (on linux)

Comment: Yes they are in the same directory (I think that, supposedly, I would be necessary os.chdir(), because no site says that in this case). Maybe it has something to do with Raspbian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printing out `os.getcwd()` will help you to debug this.

Either supply a fully qualified pathname, /some/where/test.py, or use `os.chdir('/some/where')` before executing test.py.

Comment: I tried it and it worked. But the problem is that it prints test in the same console window as the main script and I needed it to open another console window.

Comment: You don't have to fork off a python interpreter directly. You could fork off a Bourne script that calls `xterm -e python test.py`, or `os.system()` could do that directly. Man page is at https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/xterm.1.html

Comment: I tried with os.system() and it didn't open a new windows as Windows does (by the way, I'm a Python begginer).

Comment: You could be using KDE or Gnome or something else. Whatever the command is that you type at a console and it opens a new window, just supply that command to os.system(). Look at `ps axuw` output to see what commands are running currently.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't understand what you said. Can you explain that? I'm using Raspbian (if it's that what you were saying). When I execute the script with os.chdir and os.system it doesn't open a new window. It writes in the same as the main.py window.

Comment: You switched your feature request from "I want to run a program" to "I want to open a new console window and run a program." I don't know if you use Xterm, LXTerminal, gnome-terminal, Konsole or something else. Whatever it is you use (and `ps axuw` would tell you), then just run it, to create a new window. The new console window could offer an interactive bash prompt, but it could also run test.py if that's what you want. Oh wait, now I see, you found that xdg-open is winning. Consider removing the double-quotes - I doubt they help you, and the shell likely is stripping them.

Comment: Sorry for didn't explain very well, it was my first post. Anyway, I was using LXTerminal. And thanks for the tip.